# angular remove duplicates in an observable

Tags: angular, duplicates, observable, distinct

In this mat-option i'm tryng to show data from an observable i subscribed to.

```
   <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (filteredCustomer | async)?.Items"
   [value]="option" (onSelectionChange)="searchDest($event)">
   {{option.Cityname}} 
   </mat-option>
```

The name of the observable is filteredCustomer.

Now in the mat option i'm tryng to show city names. Thats the result.

```
Los Angeles
Boston
Detroit
Los Angeles
Washington
Los Angeles
```

As you can see i have duplicates.

It's possible to remove duplicates (like a distinct in sql)?

My observable come from this ts file:

```
public filterCity() {
 var parameters = new CitySearchParameters(100, 0);
 parameters.City = this.city;    
 this.filteredCustomer = this.customerService.get(parameters);
 if (typeof (this.city) == "object") {
  var curCity: any = this.city;
  this.city = curCity.City;
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output? is just a list of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Array#filter` with `Array#findIndex` to remove duplicates in an array.

```js
// credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36744732/6513921
private uniqueArray(target: Array<any>, property: any): Array<any> {
  return target.filter((item, index) =>
    index === target.findIndex(t => 
      t[property] === item[property]
    )
  );
}
```

You could then "capture" the emission from the observable in the controller using `map` operator and remove the duplicates before rendering them in the template

```js
public filterCity() {
  var parameters = new CitySearchParameters(100, 0);
  parameters.City = this.city;
  this.filteredCustomer = this.customerService.get(parameters).pipe(
    map(customer => ({
      ...customer,
      Items: uniqueArray(customer.Items, 'Cityname')  // <-- remove duplicates by `Cityname` property
    }))
  );
  if (typeof (this.city) == "object") {
    var curCity: any = this.city;
    this.city = curCity.City;
  }
}
```

The spread operator `...` is used to retain other properties in the emission from the observable except the `Items` property array. It is modified to remove the duplicates.

Comment: It works fine. In this way i have a dedicated method (the one you called uniqueArray) that will be useful in future.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

So you can convert the list the duplicates will be removed.

```
    let list = [...new Set(this.filteredCustomer)];
```

another approach to use filter

```
let chars = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'];

let uniqueChars = chars.filter((c, index) => {
    return chars.indexOf(c) === index;
});

console.log(uniqueChars); // results = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]
```

Comment: with Set method i have this error:
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(iterable?: Iterable<unknown>): Set<unknown>', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'Observable<CustomerSearchResult>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<unknown>'.
Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'Observable<CustomerSearchResult>' but required in type 'Iterable<unknown>'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(values?: readonly any[]): Set<any>', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'Observable<CustomerSearchResult>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly any[]'.

Comment: https://wsvincent.com/javascript-remove-duplicates-array/#:~:text=The%20simplest%20approach%20(in%20my,automatically%20remove%20duplicates%20for%20us.&text=Another%20option%20is%20to%20use%20filter().&text=And%20finally%20we%20can%20use%20forEach()%20.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [RxJS reduce](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/reduce) operator to keep your async pipe working, something like this, assuming that you are removing duplicates based on `.Cityname` property

```
public filterCity() {
  var parameters = new CitySearchParameters(100, 0);
  parameters.City = this.city;
  this.filteredCustomer = this.customerService.get(parameters).pipe(
    reduce((list, val) => {
      if (!list.length) return [val]
      const foundIndex = list.findIndex((item) => item.cityname === val.cityname);
      if (foundIndex === -1) {
        list.push(val);
      }

      return list;
    }, [])
  );
  if (typeof(this.city) == "object") {
    var curCity: any = this.city;
    this.city = curCity.City;
  }
}
```